# Logo must be a valid imgur link

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

Yesteday I got the invitation the the teams beta phase. I created a team and uploaded a logo from my desktop by drag and drop it into the opened screen. This worked perfectly and the logo is shown at [the team page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/140/omega-day-coding-team). I didn't put a description of the team online as I didn't have much time yesterday.

Now I wanted to edit the team and adding a description. But when I try to save the edits I only get an error "Logo must be a valid imgur link".

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops! We had to put in a regex here to block some unscrupulous users from toying around...and it didn't account for gif logos. A more comprehensive (and correct) validation check is rolling out now, you should see it on prod in about 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Editing works now. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Also, sorry about that. I've tested all of our regexes against the entirely of the data we have now so we can avoid breaks like this going forward.